# How to convert reStructuredText files with images to markdown?

Tags: markdown, restructuredtext, pandoc

I have rst files containing lines like

```
.. figure:: examples/foo.png 
    :scale: 80%

    Fig. 1 : Illustration of the awesomeness of stackoverflow
```

now I want this file to be converted into markdown. I tried using `pandoc`,

```
pandoc -s -w rst --toc foo.rst -o foo.md
```

but the output file `foo.md` seems ignore the figure inclusion lines. So, how can I convert into markdown files without losing the awesomeness of figures? Thanks

Comment: If you want to output Markdown, you don't want the `-w rst` flag, which tells it to write rst.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try) online demonstration of Pandoc converts the following markdown:

```
![Map to buried treasure](/path/to/img.jpg "Optional title")
```

into the following reStructuredText:

```
.. figure:: /path/to/img.jpg
   :align: center
   :alt: Optional title

   Map to buried treasure
```

So this should be how you can define a figure that can be converted to markdown. However, using this reStructuredText in the online converter causes an error with a very unhelpful error message. Do you get any error messages when you run Pandoc?

Perhaps your reStructuredText syntax is incorrect: options to the figure (and any other) directive should be indented with respect to the directive name. Try using

```
.. figure:: examples/foo.png 
   :scale: 80%

   Fig. 1 : Illustration of the awesomeness of stackoverflow
```

and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: there was no error reported when I ran pandoc, and my rst syntax is right - it is shown correctly elsewhere or when converted to html etc.

Comment: Then this is probably a bug with Pandoc. I would email the developers or raise this on the Pandoc mailing list/issue tracker.

Comment: Sure, and it seems that there is no alternative tools for doing the job.

Comment: One thing you could try is to convert from reStructuredText to another format, say HTML, and then convert to markdown. Not a great solution but worth giving it a go.